# Android: FileNotFoundException on an image in drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to use this code that I've seen on multiple posts throughout stackoverflow

```
    public static Bitmap loadBitmap(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
           AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
           InputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename)));
           Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

           return bitmap;
   }
```

but I'm getting a "FileNotFoundException: drawable/filename". I definitely have a file with the name I'm trying to load in the drawable folders. Any ideas? I've tried with and without the file extension, tried putting the file into every folder and tried multiple phones/emulator.

Comment: Try new BufferedInputStream((assets.open(.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawble.img)));

Comment: is your image name contain capital letter?

Answer (score 4):

The `AssetManager` is intended to access the data in the `assets` folder. So in your example, it looks for `assets/drawable/filename` and does not find anything.

To get a resource from drawable, one should use

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.filename);
```

If you're sure it's a bitmap, you can do it like so:

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.filename)).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this...

```
// load image from Assets folder
        // get input stream
        InputStream mIms = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable mDraw = Drawable.createFromStream(mIms, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        mIms.setImageDrawable(mDraw);
```