# Why does "asset not found" error occur in my code?

Tags: java, android

I have a .png file in my assets folder and I'm trying to get that image to show on screen when I tap the screen.

```
InputStream open = null;
try{
    open = asset.open("ic_launcher.png");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(open);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    if(open != null){
        try{
            open.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the `FileNotFoundException` and don't know why.

Comment: Where exactly is `ic_launcher.png` put?

Comment: the `assets` folder of my project.

Comment: is ic_launcher.png stored in assets.put your full code.initialization of asset

Comment: `project_name`/`assets`/`ic_launcher.png` ?

Answer (score 0):

Check below line of code and replace it.

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

use ,

```
 open =getAssets().open("icon.png");
```

Comment: why should it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may work.

```
 open = asset.open
("ic_launcher");
```

don't mention extentions.

Comment: That didn't work .However, I cleaned the project and restarted it. Now I get a different error. I get an NPE error..

Comment: forgot about drawable and using assets? images you store in assets doesn't get compressed. Better to use drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
try {
InputStream ims = getAssets().open("ic_launcher.png");
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
imgView.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
return;
}
```

Also [check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847954/android-filenotfoundexception-on-an-image-in-drawable)